# BibLaTeX-chicago not repeating author's name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

Novice bibliography question: when using `BibLaTeX-chicaco`, whenever I want to show the publication history of an article that's a reprint of an InCollection (using `crossref` and `related`), the author's name is not repeated in the InCollection, which makes it seem like the author is the Collection's editor.

Here's a MWE with the output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,uniquename=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@InBook{BarAsher2014a,
    author      = {Bar-Asher, Moshe},
    title       = {The Different Traditions of Mishnaic Hebrew},
    pages       = {293-327},
    crossref    = {BarAsher2014},
    related     = {BarAsher1987},
    relatedtype = {reprintof},
}

@InCollection{BarAsher1987,
    author   = {Bar-Asher, Moshe},
    title    = {The Different Traditions of Mishnaic Hebrew},
    pages    = {1--38},
    crossref = {Golomb1987},
}

@Book{BarAsher2014,
    author     = {Bar-Asher, Moshe},
    date       = {2014},
    title      = {Studies in Classical Hebrew},
    editor     = {Koller, Aaron},
    location   = {Berlin},
    publisher  = {De Gruyter},
}

@InCollection{Golomb1987,
    publisher   = {Eisenbrauns},
    title       = {``Working With No Data": Semitic and Egyptian Studies Presented to Thomas O. Lambdin},
    editor      = {Golomb, David M.},
    date        = {1987},
    location    = {Winona Lake},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Here's a sample citation of \cite{BarAsher2014a}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is what comes out. It appears like David Golomb edited the article; either the sequence of fields should be reversed (Collection's `editor` after the InCollection's `title`), or there should be some sort of 'idem.' tag in place of the InCollection's `author`.
[image: Output]

Is there a way to change this? I understand the package isn't *too* fit for personal customisation. And while I'm not absolutely fixated on `BibLaTeX-chicago`, it's been handy so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAICS `Golomb1987` should be a `@collection`, not an `@incollection`. (This doesn't help a lot with the issue at hand, but still should be fixed.)

Comment: Since the output is more reasonable with the standard `biblatex` styles, I would just report this to the `biblatex-chicago` developer. He is usually very eager to help and very responsive (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex-chicago` has some more/different related types available (you might want to check the manual). Maybe `origpubas` comes closer to what you want than `reprintof`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,uniquename=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InBook{BarAsher2014a,
    author      = {Bar-Asher, Moshe},
    title       = {The Different Traditions of Mishnaic Hebrew},
    pages       = {293-327},
    crossref    = {BarAsher2014},
    related     = {BarAsher1987},
    relatedtype = {origpubas},
}

@InCollection{BarAsher1987,
    author   = {Bar-Asher, Moshe},
    title    = {The Different Traditions of Mishnaic Hebrew},
    pages    = {1--38},
    crossref = {Golomb1987},
}

@Book{BarAsher2014,
    author     = {Bar-Asher, Moshe},
    date       = {2014},
    title      = {Studies in Classical Hebrew},
    editor     = {Koller, Aaron},
    location   = {Berlin},
    publisher  = {De Gruyter},
}

@Collection{Golomb1987,
    publisher   = {Eisenbrauns},
    title       = {``Working With No Data": Semitic and Egyptian Studies Presented to Thomas O. Lambdin},
    editor      = {Golomb, David M.},
    date        = {1987},
    location    = {Winona Lake},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Here's a sample citation of \cite{BarAsher2014a}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks. Indeed `origpubas` works better than `reprintof`, but I also found `reprintfrom` that seems to do the job.